# Ruby webscript preserving values between calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, singleton, activeadmin

I have this big problem on ruby:

```
class Finances

  @@sum = 0

  def self.add(amount)
    @@sum += amount
  end

  def self.total
    @@sum
  end

end
```

basically, an accumulator.
Problem is, It's working the first time, but it's preserving values everytime I refresh the page that uses that script. (Rails + activeadmin)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order, as: 'FinanceOrders' do
  idx = 0

  index do |x|
    column :id do
      idx += 1
    end
    column :contractor do |order|
      amount = order.contractor_payment_amount
      Finances.add amount
      amount.to_money
    end

    summary = Finances.get_summary collection

    tfoot do
      tr do
            column :contractor do |order|
              Finances.total.to_money
            end
            column :profit do |order|
              (order.sum_cost / 100).to_money * (1 - FEE) - Finances.total.to_money
            end
          end
        end
        td
      end
    end

  end

end
```

I suppose it's some kind of caching of classes on Rails. Question is, since there is a caching, how can I accomplish what I need? (Note that even idx, ids += 1 is not working. It works fine the first time, but accumulates the value of idx on every page refresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was initializing the counter and the accumulator on the module/class definition, and not on the code that was actually being executed on execution time.

The solution was this:

```
index do |x|
    Finances.start
    idx = 0
```

I created a `Finances.start` method that initializes `@@sum`, and moved the call to the index do block, along with the `idx` counter, so those values actually got initialized on every index do code execution.

It works like a charm.

Comment: You still have concurrency issues. Start a unicorn with 5 servers and use multiple requesters, then you will see what I mean. At the moment all your requests are serialized. You will see what I mean only when use a multiprocess or multithreated server and heavy load.

Comment: Do you intend that this is to be the accepted answer? If so, wait until the system times out and lets you select it. If it _isn't_ then please do not add status information as an answer. It's also undesirable to have "thanks" in an answer. SO is an online reference book, so we don't write as if it was a discussion forum. Friendliness and some familiarity is OK, but still keep it to the point.

Answer (score 2):

First, in development-mode, all classes and modules are unloaded and loaded when the containing file changes, so your class variable is reset to 0 every time Rails reloads your class.

Further more, you have to keep in mind that you are working in a threaded or multiprocess environment, depending on your web-server. Maybe you are also working in a multi-host environment, so you have to share your state between multiple threads or processes.

Class variables or class instance-variables can achieve this for multithreated environments (when you disregard race conditions), but it does not work for multiprocess or multi-host environments.

With Rails you have multiple ways to share state between your requests,  for instance, `session`, database, file system and so on.